# PHP cURL function returns 403 or 503 on websites that are working & public

Tags: php, curl

I have a curl function in PHP which I use to request the title & description of websites. I've tested it with over 1000s of different websites (using my existing bookmarks list) and it works great, but there are some websites that don't work because cURL returns a status code of either 403 or 503. For example, CodePen pens sites such as: https://codepen.io/vrugtehagel/pen/eYJjYNm returns 503 or sometimes 403 error.

This is the cURL function with the options that I have set up:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$header[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9";
$header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
$header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
$header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
$header[] = "Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8";
$header[] = "Pragma: no-cache";

// Set agent as MacBook Chrome
$user_agent_chrome = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36';

// Set cURL Options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent_chrome);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 8);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // Staging

// Execute & fetch page string data
$url_data = curl_exec($ch);

// Flag if cURL was terminated
$curl_err = curl_error($ch) ? true : false;

// Get the status (404 | 200 | ... )
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

// Get final URL (if redirection happened)
$effective_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

// Terminate connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Since these websites are publicly accessible & they work in social media sites, I'm wondering what could be setup wrong. I've searched a lot and tried other different methods. Could it be a cookie, or a particular referrer? Does anyone have a clue or maybe you have your own well-tested cURL method/options that you can share with us?

Is there an ultimate "should work everywhere" cURL example somewhere on the Web we don't know about?

I've been trying to get around this problem for almost four months now, always giving up because I can't figure out why only a few minor websites are not working. I'de appreciate if anyone can help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not uncommon for sites to block incoming requests from cloud hosts due to abuse, especially when they're faking user agents like you are.

Comment: @ceejayoz Adding a user agent is very common practice and is recommended by every post or answer I've met with - so I don't think that's the problem. Furthermore, to my knowledge there is no way to identify whether the request is coming from a cURL or a real browser. Blocking requests from know cloud providers such as AWS is something I didn't think about. I'll look into that. But I don't think it's the problem either

Comment: @ceejayoz I could add then why wouldn't a site like YouTube block such hosts? I think there's something I'm missing or doing slightly wrong - but I can't be 100% sure

Comment: 1. Adding a user agent is generally a way to get around sites blocking the cURL user agent. 2. You can easily detect cURL with a faked user agent; it tends to arrive with an empty session, it doesn't access any CSS/JS/image files, etc. 3. YouTube has plenty of bandwidth to burn on scrapers, and they *will* throw captchas at you after a while if you're doing a lot of scraping.

Comment: @ceejayoz I'm not sure you are right regarding this. Many services allow you to enter a URL and then a request is made to get OG meta data & its title. There shouldn't be a reason why a cURL request wouldn't work - it acts like a browser. The user-agent is definitely not the culprit here, and there's no way you can detect that the user agent is faked (unless you can prove it with a valid explanation). I've studied cURL, and I'm only interested why/how a website like CodePen blocks such requests. It's good to know that I'm on AWS with HTTPS connection too - if you're interested

Comment: You can be as unsure as you like. I've personally encountered sites that detect spoofed user agents and block them (again, it's pretty trivial; they just have to look at the behavior of your IP over time... does it ever request CSS/JS/images, or just HTML?), but permit well-behaved, robots.txt-respecting crawlers through. "I can't figure it out therefore it's impossible" is not a great standard.

Comment: @ceejayoz You're right regarding looking at the behaviour of IP over time. I'm sure you can figure it out eventually. Now that you mentioned crawlers that respect the robots file, you got me thinking that this might be a better approach in my case. Thanks, I'll look further into that. As for now, I actually figured a hack that if you request the URL as http, it works as long as CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION is on. Probably since it's auto-redirected on their side, it ignores certain things - not sure though.

Comment: @ceejayoz Looking into crawlers and actually under the hood they are using the same thing - cURL - and in the end I don't want to crawl deeper levels of URLs found within the page. Ultimately the most reliable method to crawl and read meta data from a website is to use the cURL method and include the options & headers as shown in my code above. Using `loadHTMLFile`, `file_get_contents` or `fopen` is also another option, but cURL is much faster. Whether or not some hosting blocks me out is something yet to be seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a temporary answer, I would like to point out the likely cause of this is CloudFlare or similar services. From the little research I did, apparently there's no workaround in cURL methods to avoid getting 403/503 status in these cases.

The best and most reliable methods so far is to use a headless browser such as Puppeteer: https://pptr.dev/ - I have not tested it in all scenarios yet, but in theory it makes sense and should work better.